# Angular 8 - JSON object not rendering in the template

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building a JSON object from a Firestore query which I want to display in the template of my Angular app. When I console log the object it appears, but trying to interpolate it into the template renders nothing.

Below is the function I'm using to get the cities.

```
getCities() {
    this.db.collection("Cities").orderBy('count', "desc").onSnapshot(function(doc) {
      let items = {}
      doc.forEach(function(data){
       items[data.id] = data.data().count
      })
      this.cities = items;
      console.log(this.cities);
      })
  }
```

Here's my code to interpolate it (Needs prettying up CSS etc) but this displays as nothing.

```
 <div *ngFor="let item of cities| keyvalue">
  {{item.key}}:{{item.value}}
</div>
```

The console log outputs this

```
{Christchurch: 27, LowerHutt: 21, Auckland: 10, Wellington: 4, Tauranga: 1, …}
```

Which is the JSON object I built. I'm not sure why I can't interpolate that into the HTML document. I've also tested and updating the database does update the console log so I think if I can interpolate it into the HTML, the page will update in real time which is what I want.

Comment: what is displayed in the view?

Comment: Hi @HamishMcBrearty is there any log of error indicate when trying to display in your Angular app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*function* has its scope([this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)). Try using arrow functions.

```
getCities() {
  this.db.collection("Cities").orderBy('count', "desc").onSnapshot((doc) =>
  {
    let items = {};
    doc.forEach((data) => {
     items[data.id] = data.data().count
    });
    this.cities = items;
    console.log(this.cities);
  });
}
```